# Is it possible to change, manually, my MacBook processor to an Intel Core i3?

Tags: macos, cpu

Is it possible to manually change my MacBook processor to an Intel Core i3?

Or should I buy a 15-inch MacBook Pro?

I wonder: is it possible to change my processor which is an Intel Core 2 Duo 2.66 Ghz to any Core i3?

Comment: Unlikely, but I've never torn one apart and looked/tried it.

Comment: Usually important laptop components (like the CPU and the GPU and some more) are soldered to the motherboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The C2D has different package specifications from the i3.

Comment: This is not even remotely close to possible. Core 2 Duo's have no memory controller, Core i3's have an on-die memory controller. The OP's computer has all the memory connected to the northbridge which is totally wrong for an i3.

Answer (score 2):

I heard that on MacBooks, processor is soldered to the board, so it would be impossible for a hardware noob. Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) article. It explains the way the processor is soldered.

Also, as others have said, C2D and i3 are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

In 99.99% of laptops it is very hard, and often impossible to change/upgrade essential compments such as the CPU. And even if it were possible to change it, obviously as mentioned previously, the two are not compatible.